# Ajax insert comment

Tags: ajax, php, mysql

Здравствуйте помогите пожалуйста.У меня есть посты и комментарии к постам.Есть такая форма для комментариев

```html
<div  id="loadplace<?php echo $post_id; ?>" > </div> 
<div id="flash<?php echo $run_post['ps_id']; ?>" class='flash_load'></div> 
<div class='panel' id="slidepanel<?php echo $run_post['ps_id']; ?>"> 
    <form action="" method="post" name="<?php echo $run_post['ps_id']; ?>">
        <textarea style="width:390px;height:23px" id="comment<?php echo $run_post['ps_id']; ?>" ></textarea>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value=" Comment_Submit " class="comment_submit" id="<?php echo $run_post['ps_id']; ?>" />
    </form>
 </div>
```

И сам обработчик

```js
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".comment_submit").click(function(){
        var element = $(this); 
        var Id = element.attr("id");
        var test = $("#comment"+Id).val(); 
        var dataString = 'comment='+ test + '&com_post_id=' + Id;

        if(test === '') { 
            alert("Please Enter Some Text"); 
        } else { 
            $("#flash"+Id).show(); 
            $("#flash"+Id).fadeIn(400).html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" align="absmiddle"> loading.....');

            $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "stena/comment.php", data: dataString, cache: false, 
                     success: function(html){ 
                                $("#loadplace"+Id).append(html); 
                                $("#flash"+Id).hide();
                                } 
                    });
        } 

        return false;
        });
});
```

И скрипт заноса комментария в базу данных.

```php
<?php 
    if(isSet($_POST['comment'])) {
        $comment = $_POST['comment'];
        $post_id = $_POST['ps_id'];
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment VALUES ('','$post_id','$myrow2[id]','$comment',now())");
    } 
?>
```

Все заносит и текст и дату и юзера айди, но не заносить id поста, помогите пожалуйста. А то не могу понять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вы в пост передаете переменную `com_post_id`, а в пхп скрипте ищете `ps_id`, которая не установлена, поэтому в базу ничего не пишется

Comment: @deivan Оо спасибо большое, а я ломал голову что я не там написал.